# Finding test dependencies of a Go program

Tags: go

I am currently using `vendor/` directory to locally vendor my dependencies.

```
go list -f '{{join .Deps "\n"}}' ./...  |grep -Eo 'vendor/.*'
```

This shows me all "build dependencies" used in my build, (that are used from `vendor/`). This feature is documented here: https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-List_packages

But it doesn't include your "test dependencies"!

So to find my "test dependencies", I run this command:

```
$ go list -f '{{join .TestImports "\n"}}' ./...  |grep -Eo 'vendor/.*'
vendor/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert
...
```

It correctly list the "test imports", but it doesn't list the "dependencies" of those test imports.

For example, the `vendor/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert` directory listed above actually depends on `vendor/github.com/pmezard/go-difflib/difflib` (and a few other packages). This is not shown in the output above!

But if I run this command, it shows the dependencies of `testify/assert`:

```
$ go list -f '{{join .Deps "\n"}}' ./vendor/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert | grep -Eo 'vendor/.*'
vendor/github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew
vendor/github.com/pmezard/go-difflib/difflib
...
```

So it appears like I need to call `go list -f '{{join .Deps "\n"}}'` on all "test imports" to find "all test dependencies"?

Is there a more efficient way of doing this, ideally with a single `go list` call and some templating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid there is no way to show all the recursive test dependencies using just one "go list".

You will need to use at least two:

```
go list -f '{{join .Deps "\n"}}' `go list -f '{{join .TestImports " "}}' ./...`
```